# Detatched construction or cloning of objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns, clone, copy-constructor

I have a class that is very complex. It has many different levels of data in large arrays. I am using this object in many different contexts.

**The problem:** We make copies of this object as it is passed along, but each spot has different requirements of what needs to be copied, and what needs to be left out. As a result, the code has grown more and more ugly with 5-6 different ways that people are copying things all over the place from copy constructors to cloning functions. It has grown ugly.

**What I want to do:** I want to decouple the construction of the object in a way that is expandable externally. If someone has a one-time-use special copy situation, I want them to be able to create a function or class in the file where it is pertinent and then pass that to a clone function.

I have thought for a while, but cannot think of any way to have an external function/object access private members (without bruteforcing it.) Here is an example of one thing I thought would work:

```
class Dolly
{
public:
    Dolly (int c = 0) : c(c) {}

    struct Cloner
    {
        virtual Dolly* operator()(Dolly const& p) const
            { return new Dolly(p.c + 1); }
    } cloneDeep;

    Dolly* clone();
    Dolly* clone(Cloner const& cloner)
        { return cloner(*this); }

protected:
    int c;
};

class ShallowCloner : public Dolly::Cloner
{
    Dolly* operator()(Dolly const& p) const
        { return new Dolly(p.c + 2); } // Error: cannot access c because its protected
} cloneShallow;
```

but the derived `ShallowCloner` cannot access its nested base class' parent's protected members (whew, what a sentence.)

If you know any solutions or design patterns that may help, let me know. Thanks

**EDIT**

After a good nights sleep, I have settled on using flags to control the copying of data. It is not too different to Mark B's answer, but is not as much code in the long run thanks to the help of flags. Here is a current framework of what I am thinking of (This is a very simplified example):

```
class Dolly
{
public:
    enum CopyData {
        D1 = 0x01,
        D2 = 0x02,
        D3 = 0x04,
        D4 = 0x08,
        DEEP = D1 | D2 | D3 | D4
    };

    Dolly(int d1 = 0, int d2 = 0, int d3 = 0, int d4 = 0) : 
            d1(d1), d2(d2), d3(d3), d4(d4) {}

    Dolly(Dolly const& cpy, int copyFlags = DEEP) {
        copyDataFrom(cpy, copyFlags);
    }

    Dolly* clone(int copyFlags) {
        return new Dolly(*this, copyFlags);
    }

    void copyDataFrom(Dolly const& cpy, int copyFlags) {
        if (copyFlags & D1) {
            copyD1From(cpy);
        }
        if (copyFlags & D2) {
            copyD2From(cpy);
        }
        if (copyFlags & D3) {
            copyD3From(cpy);
        }
        if (copyFlags & D4) {
            copyD4From(cpy);
        }
    }

    // Note that the real copies are more complex than this
    inline void copyD1From(Dolly const& cpy) { d1 = cpy.d1; }
    inline void copyD2From(Dolly const& cpy) { d2 = cpy.d2; }
    inline void copyD3From(Dolly const& cpy) { d3 = cpy.d3; }
    inline void copyD4From(Dolly const& cpy) { d4 = cpy.d4; }

protected:

    int d1;
    int d2;
    int d3;
    int d4;
};

int main()
{
    Dolly dolly(1,2,3,4);
    //Copy using constructor
    Dolly dolly2(dolly, Dolly::D1 | Dolly::D2);
    //Copy using clone
    Dolly* dolly3 = dolly.clone(Dolly::D3 | Dolly::D4);
    delete dolly3;
    //Copy using copyFrom
    Dolly dolly4;
        // Maybe do stuff here...
    dolly4.copyDataFrom(dolly, Dolly::D1 | Dolly::D3);
   return 0;
}
```

This adds a LOT of code to the class, but it does keep it clean and is safe. All the copying is kept in one place. Protected and private variables stay private. And the API stays fairly simple (<--- very important!) The user can still create a custom copy definition using the flags. Maybe I can even cut down on code using some boos variant magic. Anyway, if you have any other ideas, I am still open to hearing them.

Comment: A class should be responsible for its own copying. It sounds like the interaction between classes is not clear.

Comment: If I had several months, I would replace the object with a database-style solution, but at this time, that is not really an option for me.

Comment: Your example is too abstract for me to come up with a suggestion. If your cloning changes the state of the object, it's not really cloning. It's more of a transformation. A class should provide functions for all the transformations it supports.

Comment: The example is just to show the basic form that would be nice to have. I need an object that is like a database. I then call a copy-type function on it to get a smaller database that is a subset of the original. Currently, the clone and copy functions are getting to be too numerous and confusing. It would be nice to define the copying in the place that it is needed.

Comment: "I have a class that is very complex." That's where your trouble starts. That statement says that you need to refactor your class into a group of smaller, simpler classes.

Comment: @Rob K Complex here refers to depth not breadth. The class itself is actually not that large. I need to hold onto the original object, which has large Blitz arrays in it, while passing of copies of the original to side calculations. I don't want to copy all the irrelevant data each time I do a calculation, so that's where this complexity comes into play. Case in point, the second example above would need 24 different copy functions if I didn't use the flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with the nested class is roughly the same as using `friend` except it's just implicitly there due to being nested. And if you start allowing external classes or methods access to the private internals for this copying purpose, it will encourage mis-using such access and bypassing the public interface.

Instead what I'm going to suggest is to enforce a consistent copy mechanism within the class using tagged constructors:

```
struct DeepCopy {};
struct ShallowCopy {};
struct MagicCopy {};

class BigThing
{
public:
    BigThing() {}

    BigThing(const BigThing& right);  // Don't implement.

    BigThing(const BigThing& right, DeepCopy);  // Do the deep copy.

    BigThing(const BigThing& right, ShallowCopy);  // Do the shallow copy.

    BigThing(const BigThing& right, MagicCopy);  // Do the magic copy.
};

int main()
{
    BigThing b1;
    BigThing b2(b1, DeepCopy());
    BigThing b3(b1, MagicCopy());
}
```

Comment: My latest plan is not far from your answer. I am considering a `copyDataFrom(Dolly const&, int dataFlags)` function that takes flags for each data member in the class (a total of 20 or so flags.) Then I can make a `clone(flags = DEEP)` function and a `Dolly(Dolly const&, int dataFlags)` constructor that simply call the copyDataFrom function. This forces all copy logic into one place, but allows piecewise copying to still exist. Oh, and `copyDataFrom()` can just call `copy[bla]From()` functions for each individual datatype. Those can also be used for custom copies. Its a lot of code, but clean!